# Changing from Synchronous mindset to Asynchronous

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm busy with a windows phone application that of course uses silverlight. This means that calling any webservices has to be done asynchronously, and since this is all good and well in regards to best practice in preventing your entire app in hanging when waiting for a resource, I'm still stuck in the "synchronous mindset"...

Because the way I see it now is that you end up having 2 methods that needs to handle one function, e.g:

1)The method that actually calls the webservice:

```
public void myAsyncWebService(DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler callback)
{
    //Url to webservice
    string servletUrl = "https://deangrobler.com/someService/etc/etc"

    //Calls Servlet
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += callback;
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(servletUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

2) and the method that handles the data when it eventually comes back:

```
private void serviceReturn(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var jsonResponse = e.Result;
    //and so on and so forth...
}
```

So instead of having to just create and call a single method that goes to the webservice, gets the returned result and sent it back to me like this:

```
public string mySyncWebService(){
    //Calls the webservice
    // ...waits for return
    //And returns result
}
```

I have to in a Class call myAsyncWebService, **AND** *create* another method in the calling class that will handle the result returned by myAsyncWebService. Just, in my opinion, creates messy code. With synchronous calls you could just call one method and be done with it.

Am I just using Asynchronous calls wrong? Is my understanding wrong? I need some enlightment here, I hate doing this messy-async calls. It makes my code too complex and readability just goes to... hell.

Thanks for anyone willing to shift my mind!

Comment: Which version of C# do you use? The new `await` feature in VS2012 just avoids THIS problem (makes code more readable).

Comment: @igrimpe - I'm doing a windows phone 7 application in VS2010 express for windows phone, what version of c# would that be?

Comment: @igrimpe: The first sentence of the question: "a windows phone application that of course uses silverlight", so Windows Phone 7.5 where async and await isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn your mind inside out to program asynchronously. I speak from experience. :)

> Am I just using Asynchronous calls wrong? Is my understanding wrong?

No. Asynchronous code is fairly difficult to write (don't forget error handling) and extremely difficult to maintain.

This is the reason that `async` and `await` were invented.

If you're able to upgrade to VS2012, then you can use [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) (currently in beta) to write your code like this:

```
string url1 = "https://deangrobler.com/someService/etc/etc";
string jsonResponse1 = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(url1);

string url2 = GetUriFromJson(jsonResponse1);
string jsonResponse2 = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(url2);
```

Easy to write. Easy to maintain.

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about! Look at that nice clean, easy to understand code! I'm a bit confused though as to if I upgrade to VS2012 that I'll be able to use that. I mean coding a windows phone 7.1 app on VS2012 won't make this 'await' function available to me. But for windows phone 8 it will. So this I can only use when coding for windows phone 8 right? Opening my project in VS2012 won't just magically make the 'await' functions available for me will it? Thanks! :)

Comment: If you upgrade to VS2012, create a WP71 app, and then install the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package, then you will be able to use `await` on WP71.

Answer (score 1):

Async is like when you make a telephone call and get an answering machine, if you want a return call you leave your number. The first method is your call asking for data, the second is the "number" you've left for the return call.

Answer (score 1):

> With synchronous calls you could just call one method and be done with it.

Sure, but if you do that from the UI thread you will block the entire UI. That is unacceptable in any modern application, in particular in Silverlight applications running in the browser or in the phone. A phone that is unresponsive for 30 seconds while a DNS lookup times out is not something anybody wants to use.

So on the UI thread, probably because the user did some action in the UI, you start an asynchronous call. When the call completes a method is called on a background thread to handle the result of the call. This method will most likely update the UI with the result of the asynchronous call.

With the introduction of async and await in .NET 4.5 some of this "split" code can be simplified. Luckily async and await is now available for Windows Phone 7.5 in a beta version using the NuGet package [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.12-beta).

Here is a small (and somewhat silly) example demonstrating how you can chain two web service calls using async. This works with .NET 4.5 but using the NuGet package linked above you should be able to do something similar on Windows Phone 7.5.

```
async Task<String> GetCurrencyCode() {
  using (var webClient = new WebClient()) {
    var xml = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://freegeoip.net/xml/");
    var xElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
    var countryName = (String) xElement.Element("CountryName");
    return await GetCurrencyCodeForCountry(countryName);
  }
}

async Task<String> GetCurrencyCodeForCountry(String countryName) {
  using (var webClient = new WebClient()) {
    var outerXml = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCurrencyByCountry?CountryName=" + countryName);
    var outerXElement = XElement.Parse(outerXml);
    var innerXml = (String) outerXElement;
    var innerXElement = XElement.Parse(innerXml);
    var currencyCode = (String) innerXElement.Element("Table").Element("CurrencyCode");
    return currencyCode;
  }
}
```

However, you still need to bridge between the UI thread and the async `GetCurrencyCode`. You can't await in an event handler but you can use `Task.ContinueWith` on the task returned by the async call:

```
void OnUserAction() {
  GetCurrencyCode().ContinueWith(GetCurrencyCodeCallback);
}

void GetCurrencyCodeCallback(Task<String> task) {
  if (!task.IsFaulted)
    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
  else
    Console.WriteLine(task.Exception);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt the Async targeting pack BETA support Silvrlight 4, 5 and Phone 7.5? It's even in the NuGet repsotory I think.

Comment: @Martin Liversage - Thanks for the reply, appreciate it. Although I do understand the logic behind async calls, the problem that I'm facing now is that I need to call 2 webservices, the second one can only complete after the 1st one returns since it's waiting for data that will be returned from the first one. So I end up calling the 2nd webservice from the 1st webservice's return method. Is this the only way to get it done?

Comment: async and await is available in Silverlight 5. Just add the AsyncTargetingPack NuGet package and use Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @DeanGrobler: You are right that it becomes a bit hairy when you have to chain asynchronous calls. One option is to use TPL (Task Parallel Library) which I believe you can find implementations of for Silverlight/Windows Phone 7.5. Another alternative is to use Rx (Reactive Extensions) which is included in Windows Phone 7.5. You would then convert a return from the first web service into an `IObservable` sequence. You can then subscribe to this sequence and in the handler call the second web service. And so on. Using Rx extensions like `Timeout` would allow you to handle web service timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

It all becomes much easier and readable if you use lambdas instead. This also enables you to access variables declared in the "parent" method, like in the following example:

```
private void CallWebService()
{
    //Defined outside the callback
    var someFlag = true;

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        //Using lambdas, we can access variables defined outside the callback
        if (someFlag)
        {
            //Do stuff with the result. 
        }
    };

    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com/"));
}
```

EDIT: Here is another example with two chained service calls. It still isn't very pretty, but imho it is a little more readable than the OPs original code.

```
private void CallTwoWebServices()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        //1st call completed. Now make 2nd call.
        var client2 = new WebClient();
        client2.DownloadStringCompleted += (s2, e2) =>
        {
            //Both calls completed.
        };
        client2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com/"));
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com/"));
}
```

Comment: That is true, but I do not think it is available in Windows Phone. Come to think of it, I am not 100% sure that lambdas like the above are available either but I would be very surprised if that were so.

Comment: @henrikSoderlund - Thanks for the examples Henrik! I tried using this in my Windows Phone project and it worked. So my code it a little bit cleaner now. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid creating messy code, if you can't use the *async / await* pattern because you are on older framework, you will find helpful check [CoRoutines](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation) in their [Caliburn Micr](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)o implemantation. With this pattern you create an enumerable yielding at each turn a new asynchronous segment to execute: by the reader point of view asynchronous steps appear as a sequence, but walking among the steps ( so yielding the next one ) is done externally by asynchronously wait the single task. It is a nice pattern easy to implement and really clear to read.
BTW if you don't want to use Caliburn Micro as your MVVM tool because you are using something else, you can use just the coroutine facility, it is very insulated inside the framework.

Let me just post some code from an example in [this blog post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2009/07/10/asynchronous-execution-animation-and-more-in-mvvm-with-caliburn.aspx).

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    _credential.Username = username;
    _credential.Password = password;

    var result = new Result();
    var request = new GetUserSettings(username);

    yield return new ProcessQuery(request, result, "Logging In...");

    if (result.HasErrors)
    {
        yield return new ShowMessageBox("The username or password provided is incorrect.", "Access Denied");
        yield break;
    }

    var response = result.GetResponse(request);

    if(response.Permissions == null || response.Permissions.Count < 1)
    {
        yield return new ShowMessageBox("You do not have permission to access the dashboard.", "Access Denied");
        yield break;
    }

    _context.Permissions = response.Permissions;

    yield return new OpenWith<IShell, IDashboard>();
}
```

Isn't it easy to read? But it is is actually asynchronous: each `yield` steps are executed in an asynchronous manner and the execution flow again after the `yield` statement as soon the previous task completed.